Are there performance metrics available for Python asyncio?
I am using asyncio for working with network connections.
coro = asyncio.start_server(read_from_connection, '0.0.0.0', config.port, loop=loop)

The service becomes more heavily loaded each month, so I started worrying that one day the whole system might collapse because it will not be able to process all incoming connections and other tasks.
Right now, we have around 3000 active connections.
How can I understand where the limit is? Is it possible to receive some statistics, for example, how long a message stays in a queue or how loaded the main thread is?

I've marked this as a dupe of this question, but see also 1, 2, 3, and other similar questions related to asyncio performance measurement.
